# Echo all PHP commands on HTML (along with the output)

Tags: php

Is there a way to print/echo all the PHP command that were executed on the HTML along with whatever output (as usual) they were supposed to print?

Eg. `echo 'a'` prints '`echo 'a'`' and '`a`' both.

---

**edit**: Xdebug's http://xdebug.org/docs/code_coverage was what [what I really needed](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/reverse-engineering-php-application-without-reading-the-ugly-code) it seems.

Comment: Not really, no. PHP scripts don't work like DOS batch files in this regard. Also how would you do it practically - when I have `<?php if (x==y) echo "a"; else echo "b"; ?>` at which point would the output appear?

Comment: do you need it to print the command and the line at the same time?

Comment: maybe this can help: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php